# File does not exist at path /storage/debugbar/

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, debugging, aws-elb

We had enabled successfully debugbar in laravel, but when we inspect in the browser there showed 500 on get call. Here is exact the error

```
"exception: "Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\FileNotFoundException"
file: "/var/www/public_html/shared/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php"
line: 41
message: "File does not exist at path /var/www/public_html/releases/20200730095734/storage/debugbar/Xc528860d1984ecd3c22a9cac793a19d0.json".
```

There is AWS ALB running behind the webserver server in that case it file doesn't exist one server and the other one have. Can someone reply on it, what can be the reason?

Comment: Have your tried running `php artisan debugbar:clear`? If that doesn't work, it may be the OS directory perms of `storage/debugbar`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried that and set permissions too, the same issue. I am not sure about AWS ALB. Whenever I got the above error message at that time the missing file I can see on a different instance. Currently, there are running two ec2 instances there.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have found the problem in both you question and in your comment.

When you have DebugBar enabled, it creates a JSON file on the server in `app/storage/debugbar/{HASH}.json`. Since this file is created on the instance, it is only available to the instance on which it was created.

Amazon's Application Load Balancer (ALB) will route requests to any of your instances based on the ALB's own algorithm. This routing can result in the first request being sent to instance A on which the JSON file is generated and saved. Then a subsequent request may be routed to another instance, instance B, which does not contain the file.

The DebugBar requests a specific file based on the hash, but that file does not exist on instance B. This causes an `Illuminate\Filesystem\FileNotFoundException` to be triggered which bubbles up and results in an HTTP 500 response.

A solution, maybe the best solution for environments running DebugBar, would be to enable ["sticky sessions"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/sticky-sessions.html). Using sticky sessions you can ensure that, once you have created a session with one instance, you then stay connected to that instance.

To enabled sticky sessions, you should read the AWS documentation linked above, but as a simple example you can do:

```
aws elbv2 modify-target-group-attributes --target-group-arn ARN --attributes Key=stickiness.enabled,Value=true Key=stickiness.lb_cookie.duration_seconds,Value=86400
```

This would create a sticky session for 86400 seconds (1 day).